# T-SQL - Insert a row in a table only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the T-SQL shown below. @Results is a table variable and 'CTE' is a common table expression. I only want to insert rows into the @Results table if the SubId I'm about to insert hasn't already been inserted into the table. The code shown below doesn't do the job and I'm not sure why. Can anyone see the problem?

```
Insert Into @Results (
    Cell, 
    CellSettings, 
    RecipeInstanceId, 
    BiasStartTime, 
    SubId 
    RuleInstanceId)
Select 
    Cell, 
    CellSettings, 
    RecipeInstanceId, 
    BiasStartTime, 
    SubId, 
    RuleInstanceId
From CTE
Where CTE.SubId NOT IN (Select SubId From @Results)
```

Comment: what is the problem ? Errormessage?

Comment: you may have to post the cte as well - or even better: boil it down to a smaller demonstration. May your problem even solves itself by doing so... ;)

Comment: Do you receive an error message when adding a duplicate?

Comment: The code you have shown does the job exactly as specified. I can only assume your question is due to PK errors or finding duplicates afterwards. **NB:** The duplicates are due to duplicates in the **source CTE**, not an error in the WHERE clause. You might have expected this to resolve duplicates by checking checking later rows against rows added earlier in the insert.... This is ***not*** the way SQL works. The entire insert is evaluted as a single operation. Values already in `Results` at the _start_ would not be inserted; but 5 rows with the same `SubId` would all be inserted otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check for existance first:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Results WHERE SubId = .......)
   INSERT INTO @Results (Cell, CellSettings, RecipeInstanceId, 
                          BiasStartTime, SubId, RuleInstanceId)
     SELECT 
         Cell, CellSettings, RecipeInstanceId, 
         BiasStartTime, SubId, RuleInstanceId
     FROM CTE
```

Maybe you could put this requirement (only return those rows that don't already exist) into your CTE so that you won't have to filter the output from the CTE yet again...

Comment: Isn't it better to use a join?

Comment: @Hogan: no - why? What do you think you can gain from using a JOIN instead??

Comment: because this check has to be done for each row (a new select) where a join is optimized in SQL to work quickly on sets of date.  It is the difference between O(n) optimized vs O(1)+O(1)+...+O(1) n times.  (See my answer for an example of using the join.)

Comment: @Hogan: I would think the best approach would be to filter out those rows that already exist in the target table in the CTE and not return those at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this (assumption - you don't have duplicate SubID in your CTE, that is you insert SubID of X and then later in this same query you insert the same one.)

```
WITH CTE AS
( 
  blah
), CTENEW AS
(
   SELECT CTE.* 
   FROM CTE
   LEFT JOIN @Results R ON CTE.SubID = R.SubID
   WHERE R.SubID IS NULL
)
Insert Into @Results (
    Cell, 
    CellSettings, 
    RecipeInstanceId, 
    BiasStartTime, 
    SubId 
    RuleInstanceId)
Select 
    Cell, 
    CellSettings, 
    RecipeInstanceId, 
    BiasStartTime, 
    SubId, 
    RuleInstanceId
From CTENEW
```

Or you could roll the join I made into your CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Try an `except clause:

```
insert MyTable(c1, c2, c3)

select ot.c1, ot.c2, ot.c3
from OtherTable ot

except

select mt.c1, mt.c2, mt.c3
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the record exists or not using "Exists"

```
If Not Exists(Select SubId From @Results)
    Insert Into @Results (
        Cell, 
        CellSettings, 
        RecipeInstanceId, 
        BiasStartTime, 
        SubId 
        RuleInstanceId)
    Select 
        Cell, 
        CellSettings, 
        RecipeInstanceId, 
        BiasStartTime, 
        SubId, 
        RuleInstanceId
    From CTE
    Where CTE.SubId NOT IN (Select SubId From @Results)
```